# When UIButton is held, increment by pre-set int value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working for a client that wants his button - when pressed - to add a preset value to a value in a text field, but when held to increment while held by the same amount. I've been looking all afternoon and I can't find a solid answer on this.

I am working off his code and his increment code is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)incrementInput1:(id)sender{  
  inputValue1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",[[inputValue1 text] floatValue]+inc1];  
  note.text=@" ";
  [self calcValue];
}
```

This is for each button (of which there are four).

Thank you so much for reading and extra thanks if you help out :-D

Comment: "but when held to increment while held by the same amount" what is it that you actually mean by this?

Comment: inputValue1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",[[inputValue1 text] floatValue]+inc1]; .......... is the line where you have problem? had you tried..... with %f as string format?

Comment: @7KV7 eg, you hold the button it runs the action again and again until the user releases the button.

Comment: @Ravin This is his previous coders code, not mine, I've been told to work around his code and not change it too much, but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
-(void)incrementValue:(id)sender {
   <Code to increment value>
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSArray *array = [touches allObjects];
    UITouch *specificTouch = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    currentTouch = [specificTouch locationInView:yourUIbuttonName];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourUIbuttonName.bounds, currentTouch)) {
               timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(incrementValue:) repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   if (timer != nil) 
      [timer invalidate];
      timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: add "userInfo:nil" before the "repeats:YES" if you get an error on that line

Answer (score 0):

initiate a time in action triggered by touchedDownInside, which will increment your value and repeat.

Then, stop the timer in action triggered when touches ended.